# Run an apps script code containing an If Statement (How To Trigger Automatically ?) - Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below which runs as intented - if you manually run the script.

Data appears in this sheet("TOP UP NEEDED") via MoveRow Script (No Human Editing)

```
 function IfStatement() {
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var activeSheet = app.getActive().getActiveSheet();
 var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
 if (workingCell === "") return;  // Modified

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
 sheet.getRange('D2').activate();

 sheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=QUERY({\'SKU & Qty\'!$A$3:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & 
 JOIN("|",FILTER(A:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))) & "\' ")');

 addCheckboxToI2();

 MoveDataToFORKLIFT();

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A2:G30').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();

DELETESHEETS();

addCheckboxToG2FORKLIFT(); 
}
```

Currently when the data arrives in "TOP UP NEEDED" - script does not run.

Expected Result = When A2:A has data it should run the script. When A2:A "" - nothing should happen.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Thank you for the information. In above modification, when the cells "A2:A" are not empty, the script is run. At that time, the formula is put to the cell "D2" of the sheet "TOP UP NEEDED" in the active Spreadsheet. I could understand your question like this. But from your additional information, I thought that my answer might not be suitable for your goal. So my answer should be deleted, because I don't want to confuse other users. When I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Is `TOP UP NEEDED` in the same spreadsheet as `PrepSheet`? If that's the case, why are you copying the sheet `PrepSheet` to another spreadsheet? (`var tempSheet = s.copyTo(targetSS);`)

Comment: Hi iamblichus - they are seperate folders I am sorry. really stumped on this one, so for the moment its run by time based trigger

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to place your desired code below the `MoveRow` code. But you'd need to clarify what the code is doing (including that is, if the script is working with several spreadsheets), and crucially, it would be really useful if you shared a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet/s you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

If your function `IfStatement()` already works, simply call it at the end of your MoveRow script.

Comment: Diego - The MoveRow script is located on another spreadsheet in a completely different folder. The MoveRow copies row and sends it to TopUpNeeded via openbyID etc etc. I Tried the OnFormSubmit as that should fire as data comes into TopUpNeeded - thats right isnt it ?

Comment: So I have it set to run time based until I can figure this out.

Comment: @TomSawkins No, the only way to fire an onEdit trigger is if a user manually edits the sheet. The spreadsheet and folder you call `IfStatement()` from doesn't really matter. You can move your function into that file and call it then.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying - add IfStatement script to end of MoveRow script ?

Comment: @TomSawkins How is the data being entered in column A?

Comment: var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
    s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var tempSheet = s.copyTo(targetSS);
   var targetSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName("TOP UP NEEDED");

Comment: @TomSawkins Okay, so yes, you understood what I was saying–you can  add the `IfStatement()` code to your MoveRow script and then call it immediately after  adding the data in column A. Of course, you'll need to modify the code to select the correct spreadsheet & sheet.

Comment: Ok I am coding that right now. it will be some piece of script !!. the MoveRow script is being handled by an onEdit so lets see how it goes. I can say I have never tried this before. So I am sending the script to another sheet and then once there it runs the script associated with that sheet, interesting. thanks diego will let you know how It goes if thats ok ?

Comment: Diego - it only ran the MoveRow script only. see link if you get a chance  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q7O-kb_3wOXNdgmibFf5bup4qQkLQPqOcyqQ0p8f_Nk/edit#gid=0